# Sort array based on text in the middle of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array that goes something like this:

```
var array=['Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
           'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
           'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
           'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 3 PM',
           'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
           'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
           'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 8 AM',
           'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 2 PM',
           'The London Centre Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
           'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
           'Professional Centers-NY Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM',
           'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
           'Professional Centers-NY Saturday, July 7, 2018 10 AM',
           'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 9, 2018 9 AM',
           'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 8 AM',
           'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 2 PM',
           'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 8 AM',
           'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 2 PM',
           'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM'];
```

can the array be sorted based on the date in the middle of the string at an array index, such that the result array will be:

```
['Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
 'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
 'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
 'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
 'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
 'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
 'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 8 AM',
 'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 2 PM',
 'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
 'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 3 PM',
 'The London Centre Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
 'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 8 AM',
 'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 2 PM',
 'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 8 AM',
 'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 2 PM',
 'Professional Centers-NY Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM',
 'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM',
 'Professional Centers-NY Saturday, July 7, 2018 10 AM',
 'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 9, 2018 9 AM'];
```

Comment: This is not a jquery question. But yes you can. What is the issue with your attempt?

Comment: Yes it can. You need to implement your own logic in [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The hardest part of this will be turning that date format in to Date objects which can be effectively sorted.

Comment: Do you also expect there to be further sorting on "some data one", "some data two", etc.?  That is a harder problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet edited my data set, basically on date and then on AM PM if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to extract the part with the date to compare its value, this can be achieved by passing a custom function to `Array.sort` - But be aware that the conversion of Dates is highly dependent from Browsers - you might want to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for a robust date conversion. For me this script works perfectly fine in Chrome, but it could be that it will not in other Browsers.

```js
var array = ['Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
             'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
             'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
             'Professional Centers-Beijing, China Wednesday, July 4, 2018 3 PM',
             'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
             'The London Centre Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
             'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 8 AM',
             'The London Centre Tuesday, July 3, 2018 2 PM',
             'The London Centre Wednesday, July 4, 2018 9 AM',
             'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 9 AM',
             'Professional Centers-NY Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM',
             'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 2, 2018 3 PM',
             'Professional Centers-NY Saturday, July 7, 2018 10 AM',
             'Professional Centers-NY Monday, July 9, 2018 9 AM',
             'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 8 AM',
             'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Wednesday, July 4, 2018 2 PM',
             'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 8 AM',
             'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Thursday, July 5, 2018 2 PM',
             'CTU Training Solutions Cape Town Friday, July 6, 2018 8 AM'];
 
function dateParser(d) {
  // This splits the string at each , and joins the last two parts
  let dateString = d.split(', ').slice(-2).join(', ').trim();
  // Without moment.js this could not be easily parsed so you need it
  return moment(dateString, 'MMMM D, YYYY H A');
}

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return dateParser(a) - dateParser(b)
});
 
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're right, i totally forgot about that - i am way too used to them and having a transpiler running over my JS files before deploying :) Updating

Comment: your snippet did work on my initial sample that I gave but when I ran it on my original data it failed. I have edited the question to the data it is going to run on

Comment: I see, there could be more `, ` before the date - editing my code

Comment: yes but the number of
`,  `
are not the same for each index for instance the first four indexes have two
`,  `
 before the date and the remaining have only one

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks! :)